# Using Yield Within While Loop (PriorityQueue Implementation)

Tags: c#, .net, yield-return

I have been playing around with various implementations of a `PriorityQueue<T>` class lately, and I have come across some behavior I do not fully understand.

Here, is a snippet from the unit test I am running:

```
PriorityQueue<Int32> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<Int32>();

Randomizer r = new Randomizer();
priorityQueue.AddRange(r.GetInts(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue, r.Next(300, 10000)));

priorityQueue.PopFront(); // Gets called, and works correctly

Int32 numberToPop = priorityQueue.Count / 3;
priorityQueue.PopFront(numberToPop); // Does not get called, an empty IEnumerable<T> (T is an Int32 here) is returned
```

As I noted in the comments, the `PopFront()` gets called and operates correctly, but when I try to call the `PopFront(numberToPop)`, the method does not get called at all, as in, it does not even enter the method.

Here are the methods:

```
    public T PopFront()
    {
        if (items.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No elements exist in the queue");
        }

        T item = items[0];
        items.RemoveAt(0);
        return item;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> PopFront(Int32 numberToPop)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("PriorityQueue<T>.PopFront({0})", numberToPop);
        if (numberToPop > items.Count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(@"The numberToPop exceeds the number of elements in the queue", "numberToPop");
        }

        while (numberToPop-- > 0)
        {
            yield return PopFront();
        }
    }
```

Now, previously, I had implemented the overloaded PopFront function like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<T> PopFront(Int32 numberToPop)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PriorityQueue<T>.PopFront({0})", numberToPop);
        if (numberToPop > items.Count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(@"The numberToPop exceeds the number of elements in the queue", "numberToPop");
        }

        var poppedItems = items.Take(numberToPop);
        Clear(0, numberToPop);
        return poppedItems;
    }
```

The previous implementation (above) worked as expected. With all that being said, I am obviously aware that my use of the `yield` statement is incorrect (most likely because I am removing then returning elements in the `PopFront()` function), but what I am really interested in knowing is why the `PopFront(Int32 numberToPop)` is never even called and, if it is not called, why then is it returning an empty `IEnumerable<Int32>`?

Any help/explanation to why this is occurring is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to enumerate the enumerable returned by the yield return.

Comment: People who want to pop more than one item at a time.

Comment: Even your previous code probably incorrect (without the full implementation, we can't say for sure).  `Take` is going to defer execution, so if you don't iterate the results until after some other pops take place...bad things could happen.  A method like this should eagerly modify the queue and eagerly materialize the results.  Deferring execution at all is a recipe for sublte bugs.

Comment: @Servy Extremely good advice there.

Comment: @Servy Curious to how you would go about implementing it?  Looping and adding the item return from PopFront() to some local list, which is returned?

Comment: @DavidVenegoni That's certainly an option, yes.  You may also be able to use, say `ToList` to simply eagerly materialize the query, but again, without a full implementation, it's hard to say what's valid/desirable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `yield return`, the compiler creates a state machine for you. Your code won't start executing until you start to enumerate (`foreach` or `ToList`) the `IEnumerable<T>` returned by your method.

From the [`yield` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx)

> On an iteration of the foreach loop, the MoveNext method is called for elements. This call executes the body of MyIteratorMethod until the next yield return statement is reached. The expression returned by the yield return statement determines not only the value of the element variable for consumption by the loop body but also the Current property of elements, which is an IEnumerable.
>
> On each subsequent iteration of the foreach loop, the execution of the iterator body continues from where it left off, again stopping when it reaches a yield return statement. The foreach loop completes when the end of the iterator method or a yield break statement is reached.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, I was unaware that the compiler created a state machine, so essentially, it is kind of like a task waiting to be started?

Comment: I will, have to wait 5 more minutes apparently.

Comment: @DavidVenegoni Don't miss Servy's advice above, this does not appear to be a very good idea.