# Returning generic parameter T with yield return

Tags: generics, casting, yield, return-type

I want to generate a list of types (which is inherited from class T) from a loaded dll file. But when I use the following code, application becomes frozen/stuck:

```
static IEnumerable<T> GetAllTypes<T>(string dllName)
{
    Assembly plugin = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllName);
    if (plugin != null)
    {
        Type[] types = plugin.GetTypes();
        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            if (type.IsClass && type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
                yield return (T)(Object)type;
            }
        }
    }
    else
        throw new InvalidDataException();
}
```

However, if I do not use the yield return, everything works as expected and no freezing occurs . Can anyone explain this behavior?

```
static void GetAllTypes<T>(string dllName)
{
    Assembly plugin = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllName);
    if (plugin != null)
    {
        Type[] types = plugin.GetTypes();
        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            if (type.IsClass && type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
                //yield return (T)(Object)type;
            }
        }
    }
    else
        throw new InvalidDataException();
}
```

Comment: yield can be sensitive in loops, since it is an iterator based state machine. check out the answer to this question, it might help you out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982371/using-yield-within-while-loop-priorityqueue-implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `type` is an **instance of `System.Type`**. You should just (yield)  return it, and make `IEnumerable<System.Type>` the return type.

Your type cast code tries to convert that object to an **instance of `T`** which is invalid and impossible, it can't ever work. An object of type T is not the same as the Type T itself, but that is what your code is trying to force.

Not sure if a 'hang' could be the result but the casting code is just wrong.

Comment: Yes, I found it impossible to cast this way! changing the <T> to <System.Type> seems work it around. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

Your application probably isn't stuck, the problem is that iterators are *lazy*. You've built a question but you haven't actually asked it yet.

```
var types = GetTypes("Foo");
```

This will only create a query but it won't actually execute it. This will:

```
foreach (var t in types) { ... }
```

That said, your code will never work as explained in other answers. `typeof(T)` and a `T` are completely different things.